# Can't store fetched message in a variable - Discord js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to fetch a message using

```
client.channels.cache.get("id").messages.fetch("id")
```

But when I try to use it, the properties are undefined.

The only way I found to use the fetched message is adding `.then(message => )`, but I can't store it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple fix for your variable, you should use async/await, so turn your command handler into async

```js
execute: async (bot, message, args) => { ... }
```

Or if you are using the message event you can do this:

```js
bot.on('message', async msg => {
   // . . .
});
```

Then put this code inside and it should work fine, as you need to wait for the variable to be filled with the content.

```js
let lastmessage = "";

await bot.channels.cache.get("ID").messages.fetch("ID").then(message => lastmessage = message.content );
msg.reply(lastmessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **variable outside that logic** in order to store something, like:

```
let lastMessage = '';
client.channels.cache.get("id").messages.fetch("id").then(message => lastMessage = message);
```

Comment: I tried that, but it still says that it's undefined